# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined with mongoose and jest and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, jestjs

I am using Node 14 with express v4.16.3 and typescript (v4.7.4); after adding mongoose (v6.5.2) to the project, the logic code works fine but most of the tests, run by jest (v26.4.2), are failing with error message:

`ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined.`
The error is thrown from `node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js:2:21`

I have read all other questions about this error on SO but none of the solution works for me. A lot of them saying adding
`global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder`; but where to do this exactly? I tried to add it to the `jest.config.js` but didn't make any difference.
Tried to add it to the file which references `mongoose` and it says `property TextEncoder doesn't exist on global of type Global`

A lot of people suggest editing the `encoding.js` file manually; don't think this is a sustainable solution at all so didn't even try. Some suggest upgrading node to 12 or higher, which doesn't apply to me as I am using node 14.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out; the following fixed my problem, within `jest.config.js`, add:

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "node",
}
```